# apache redirect rules for multimple domains | https://www

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two applications configured on one apache (eg. example.com and test.net). Rewrite rules for those apps are the same (so in config file for domain example.com I've got this rules, and the same rules in conf file for test.net domain)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

And it almost works ok, except for one case - when I request in webwrowser `https://www.test.net`.
In this only case apache redirets to `https://www.test.net but displays content of https://www.example.com (not content of https://www.test.net as it should). Request www.test.net works ok. And https://www.example.com also works ok.`

#### And here's whole Virtual Host config for test.net (config for example.com is analogical):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.net
    ServerAlias www.test.net

    DocumentRoot /var/www/test/web/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/test/web/>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test_access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on  

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}


</VirtualHost>
```

#### And Virtual Host file for example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/example/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/example/>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example_error.log
        LogLevel warn   
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example_access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</VirtualHost>
```

I've got also ofcourse config file for ssl settings (eg. ssl certs), but there's no redirect rules.

How to configure rewrite rules for this two applications so that it work properly?

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to redirect and HTTP traffic to HTTPS; am I correct in assuming this?

If yes, try this:

Remove this:

```
RewriteEngine on  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

and replace it with this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't change a thing. It looks like every request contains www. (so `https://www.test.net` to) is caught by the application example.com config (?), because `https://www.test.net` redirets to `https://www.test.net` but displays content of example.com application. Thanks for suggestion! Still searching

Comment: Check your example.com conf and make sure there isn't a reference to test.net - or just edit your question and post it there.

Comment: I've just added virtual host config for example.com to my question. Any suggestions very appreciated! :) So far don't know where my mistake is.